# How to place the items based on some conditions in Pandas or Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I am little new to python and I am facing challenges and getting bugs while writing some tricky code. It would be really kind if you could help:

Scenario:
I have two datasets as follows:
One is:

```
        Location  
    0   loc1   
    1   loc2   
    2   loc3   
    3   loc4    
    4   loc5   
    5   loc6    
    6   loc7   
    7   loc8
    8   loc9...and so on.
```

And another one is:

```
        Item    Rank     Weight
    0   1001    1        18
    1   1002    2        21
    2   1003    3        20
    3   1004    4         7
    4   1005    5        27
    5   1006    6        20
    6   1007    7        11
    7   1008    8        31
    8   1009    9        30
    9   1010    10       23 and so on
```

I want to create one function to allocate each item a slot on the basis of it's rank and weight. Where rank 1 means high and whatever number is highest say 100 that would be lowest rank.

If the rank is highest i.e. then I need to place the item to the first location. And the 2nd highest rank item to 2nd location and so on. But while placing the location I also check the weights whether it is more than 25 or not and if the it more than 25 then I don't want to allocate them at loc4, loc5 & loc6

For eg: if I have 1005 which has the rank 5 but weight 27 that is greater than 25 then I won't place them at loc4 or loc5 or loc6 location. I will place that whatever next available location.

Expected output:

```
        Item    Rank    Weight Location
    0   1001    1        18     loc1 
    1   1002    2        21     loc2
    2   1003    3        20     loc3
    3   1004    4         7     loc4
    4   1005    5        27     loc7
    5   1006    6        20     loc5
    6   1007    7        11     loc6
    7   1008    8        31     loc8
    8   1009    9        30     loc9 
    9   1010    10       23     loc10
```

Please help

Comment: Why 1010 has the loc10 and not the loc7?

Comment: @Corralien because the next available location after 9th rank item got located is loc10 right? And the 1010 has rank 10, that's why

Comment: But the weigh of 1010 is 23 which lower than 25 while locations 1008 and 1009 have a weight greater than 25. I don't understand why (1005, 1006, 1007) is different of (1008, 1009, 1010)

Comment: Greater than 25 is heaver weight and that's the reason I am not putting them on loc4, loc5 & loc6. Because loc4, loc5, loc6 is top of the rack. Whereas rest of the locs are not the part of top of the rack. So I can placed heavier items there

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's say you have your items in a `list` of `tuples` (you may want to use `namedtuples` for clarity):

```
items = [(1001,1,18), (1002,2,21), (1003,3,20), (1004,4,7), (1005,5,27), (1006,6,20), (1007,7,11), (1008,8,31), (1009,9,30), (1010,10,23)]
```

and let's build a location `dict`:

```
locations = {loc: None for loc in range(1,20)}
```

Then we just need to know what locations are "top", and what is the max weight they can accept, and here we go:

```
toplocs=[4,5,6]
maxweight = 25

for i in sorted(items, key=lambda x:x[1]):
    if i[2] > maxweight:
        newloc = next(loc for loc,v in locations.items() if v is None and loc not in toplocs)
    else:
        newloc = next(loc for loc,v in locations.items if v is None)
    locations[newloc] = i[0]
```

Comment: Hey it's throwing me an error when I am using pandas dataframes instead of tuples and lists

Comment: If you want to use pandas you have to adapt the syntax - dataframes are not simple Python sequence objects (but you can still apply the same logic)